# Backing Up Windows Server 2016 - Acroins Server 12 - Web GUI ONLY?

Tags: backup, windows-server-2016, acronis

first of all i used Acronis since Version 9. V10 was okay. But did they really completely change from Windows-GUI to Web-GUI in V12?

Is there any way to get the Windows-GUI back, where i can make more detailed settings?

While i am not against web-interfaces - Acronis seems to change their layout with every version *ARGH* making you relearn - relearn - relearn - i really wonder what was the idea behind this change? It feels "sluggish".

[Acronis 12 Web Gui Screenshot](http://dwaves.de/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Acronis-12-Web-GUI-Firefox.png)
 (why are pictures not displayed inline anymore?)

The server-version was pretty expensive (7XXUSD?) and unfortunately it does not seem like things improved from my point of view from version 10 onwards.

I am seriously considering returning / getting rid of it... ShadowProtect has a better Windows-based-GUI than Acronis. (it is more complex but still managable)

And there is also veeam which is said to be very good... but also expensive 750USD.

The Server is also running VirtualBox VMs and Microsoft SQL-Server... i really wonder what is the best way to backup those...

Comment: I'm not sure why you think we'd have an answer or insight on this. 
Why don't you direct your question the the vendor. This site isn't the place for you to rant about product features or the lack thereof.

Answer (score 2):

I have the answer right here in my hand:  the bootable disk.

Yes, it uses a Linux-based GUI, but it is the ultimate way to use Acronis.  No Windows involved.

But of course you have the option of running it under Windows where it first makes a Volume Shadow Copy and you can keep working while it runs.  That may be important on a server.

But this bootable media is worth some downtime.  It will run on any computer that has a CD drive, and never fails.

All you have to do is buy one copy of True Image 2017 and make the bootable media.

And when I have had questions they have always been very responsive.

It is very inexpensive to try it out.  Their licensing terms are very generous but to make the bootable media only requires one license.

Highly recommended.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really a user of Acronis Backup 12, but the following quote from [Vasily Semyonov](https://forum.acronis.com/user/55) (Acronis Virtualization Program Manager) in the [Acronis Forum](https://forum.acronis.com/) seems to confirm that product version doesn't have a "classic" traditional GUI anymore, but only a web interface / web console (the **bold emphasis** is mine):

https://forum.acronis.com/comment/384606#comment-384606

> (...) *We have Acronis Backup 12 which is a logical successor of Acronis
>   Backup 11.7 non-Advanced edition and Acronis Backup for VMware 9.
>   (...) **The significant redesign of the GUI (switching it to web) is a
>   big challenge for us and it is a part of "single-code-base-platform"
>   paradigm which we stick to.** This paradigm means that all Acronis
>   products in the nearest couple of years will be running on the same
>   single code base and thus the fixes/new features we make will be
>   applied to all products simultaneously. Then we won't need to
>   re-implement the same fixes for different products as we do now.*

Comment: If that is true then I'll happily stay with TI 2017.  It has everything I need.